# In The Phantom Tollbooth, where does Norton Juster get this "fact" about witches from?

Tags: witches, the-phantom-tollbooth

I'm rereading *[The Phantom Tollbooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_Tollbooth)*, and a sentence struck out at me that I haven't noticed before:

> Milo jumped back in fright and quickly grabbed Tock to make sure that his alarm didn't go off—for he knew how much witches hate loud noises.

Is Norton Juster referencing a certain book or other source here? Where did he get this "fact" about witches?

Comment: First Phantom Tollbooth question. Very surprising. If you haven't I really recommend you read it.

Comment: [Nicholas Remy (1594)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=aC3HnFWKV-UC&q=gongs#v=onepage&q=bell&f=false) vouchsafed that bells (and in particular consecrated church bells) were a sovereign specific against demons and witches; https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojNEV.png

Comment: it was made into a live action / animated movie was well - Chuck Jones animated - less than stellar compared to the book but still - quite surprised you've *never* heard of it - heck, it's even referenced in an episode of "Parks and Recreation" :D

Comment: @TheAsh I’m American and grew up with both the book and the movie and they never breathed a word of it my entire school career as I moved up and down the east coast every year or two. I fear that I must disagree with the commonality here in the US.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what Juster intended, but the connection I made as a child was to "Hansel and Gretel."  The witch with the gingerbread house has extremely sensitive hearing, so that she can hear the children taking bites out of her cottage:

> Nibble, nibble, little mouse.
>   Who's been nibbling at my house?